# Format link to open in desired browser (Chrome)

Tags: 2010, chrome, ie

Is it possible to force a link within a SharePoint site to open in a certain browser?

We have an online system that works best in Chrome. I've placed a link to this system in a library on our site - however, it will open in IE if that happens to be your default browser.

Ideally, a user would click the link and it would open in Chrome, but I've looked through the library settings and there seems to be no options related to "forcing a link to open in a specific browser."

Has anyone encountered this issue, and can it be solved within SharePoint? Thanks.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but can you elaborate on this bit: Code snippet to call Chrome.exe would be as follows:
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://sp.path.to/your/file.doc") Where would I place that. I should add I'm no code writer so If you could provide a step by step I'd be grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

OOTB, SharePoint only opens in browser which is set as default.

However, if this customization is absolutely necessary,you can develop a server side web part in which you can generate a link.Clicking on which will execute `Chrome.exe` process and open the link in browser.

Code snippet to call `Chrome.exe` would be as follows:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://sp.path.to/your/file.doc")
```